# Hensel's lemma and lifting roots of unity

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am new to Hensel's lemma and my syllabus uses the following theorem:

**$(\mathbb Z_p $ denotes the p-adic integers)**

Given $f\in \mathbb Z_p[X]$ , if $\exists \alpha_0\in \mathbb Z_p$ :$f(\alpha_0)=0$ mod $p$ but $f'(\alpha_0)\neq 0$ mod $p$, then $\exists!\alpha\in \mathbb Z_p$ :$f(\alpha)=0$ and $\alpha=\alpha_0$ mod $p$.

[Here](https://wstein.org/edu/2007/spring/bsd/bsd/node10.html#lem:hensel) one uses the following (equivalent?) theorem: if $f\in \mathbb Z_p[X]$ and $\beta\in \mathbb Z/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a multiplicity one root of $\overline{f}$, then there is a unique lift $\beta$ to a root of $f$.

I don't understand how these two theorems say the same thing. Can we see an inclusion $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}_p$ or is there something deeper?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: some abbreviate $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ as $\mathbb Z_p$

Comment: $\mathbb Z_p$ are the p-adic integers, now edited , thanks

Answer (score 2):

For this to make sense, you need to have an understanding that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the inverse limit of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n=1, 2, \dots$. If you aren't familiar with inverse limits, then I highly recommend learning about them. They are crucial for understanding the $p$-adics, and putting them off will only hurt in the long run.

In short, a $p$-adic integer can be constructed by giving a consistent system of residues modulo $p^n$ for each $n$. This is exactly what the lifting theorem does.

Edit: Hensel's lemma is often stated as lifting a solution modulo $p^n$ to one modulo $p^{n+1}$, see for example [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Alternative_statement). Doing this for every $n$, one gets a set of solutions $(s_1, s_2, \dots)$ where $s_n$ is a solution modulo $p^n$. This is a $p$-adic integer, by definition of the $p$-adic integers as an inverse limit.

Comment: I know about the inverse limit, could you elaborate?

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz: I added some elaboration.